# access client side controls on the server

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I am applying a field validator on a listbox which works when no item is selected in the textbox and some(most often the submit button) control is made to postback to the server.

Now the problem is that if a person has entered the page and want to logout it still gives the same exception messages(which it should) rather than logging out of the page.

I am using ASP.NET with c# as back-end.
I want the the logout button(rather all except the submit button) to function prior to the validation please help. Thank you vary much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different method:

- set the logout button "CauseValidation" property to false (if it's a asp.net button)
- set the ValidationGroup property for your validator. In ASP.NET there's this property for buttons (which raise postback) and for validators.
  For your problem, simply set logout button ValidationGroup Property different
  Using ValidationGroup you can have different validation levels into the same page. 
  On MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx